# Monotouch/iOS: which place is the best one to unsubscribe the delegate

Tags: ios, delegates, xamarin.ios, unsubscribe

The best method in iOS to subscribe a event is ViewDidLoad, but when dismiss the view , the ViewDidUnload() is not called(only when the memory warning.)

Which place is the best to unsubscribe the event?

(In the subviewController I subscribe a event that reference the MainViewController, When open the subview twice, I receive two event trigger because the unsubscribe in viewdidunload() is never called.)

How about with subscribe/unsubscribe in ViewWillAppear/ViewWillDisapper?

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        this.mBL.OrderChanged += HandleOrderChanged;            
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        base.VieWillDisappear (animated);
        if (this.mBL!=null)
          this.mBL.OrderChanged -= HandleOrderChanged;          
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewDidUnload`, those are the appropriate places to subscribe/unsubscribe events from the UI.

Here is a general article on memory management in iOS that I think applies here: http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/buildingiphoneapps/2010/6/25/memory-management-and-viewdidunload.html

Now, if you're not wanting to have the event run when your View is not visible, do something like this in the event handler:

```
if (IsViewLoaded && View.Window != null) {
  //code here
}
```

I've found this is the easiest way to tell if the view is on screen.

Comment: What's wrong with using ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear()? Then no checks are required. And another question about your check: if you call "View.Window" inside ViewDidUnload, won't the "View" call load the view again?

Comment: I would perfet using ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear, thanks.

Comment: Note that inside a UINavigationController, ViewWillAppear and ViewWillDisappear may not function like you expect.  ViewWillAppear/Disappear won't get called when a controller is pushed overtop.  Similar happens with modal view controllers.

Comment: There might be a serious fault in this code: reading value of `View` property when a view is unloaded [forces it to get loaded in memory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). So you should perhaps modify your condition to be `if (IsViewLoaded && View.Superview != null)`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the best time is in ViewWillAppear/ViewWillDisappear, not ViewDidUnload.

ViewDidUnload is called called post iOS 6: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIViewController.ViewDidUnload()/