# How to remove an observer in Monotouch iOS app when ViewController is closed

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsnotificationcenter, observers

I have a few view controllers in my MonoTouch application that are using the NSNotificationCenter to listen for certain events that may be triggered in my application. As long as the controllers are still in the stack, they should be listening and update (even if they aren't the currently visible view.)

How do I go about removing the listener when the view is no longer in the current stack (either by using the back button, dismissing the controller by itself, or after calling PopToRootController)?

Comment: should solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155281/monotouch-ios-which-place-is-the-best-one-to-unsubscribe-the-delegate

Comment: Sadly, moritz, it doesn't seem to fix my issue.  It talks about ViewDidDisappear, which doesn't work for my case, and ViewDidUnload, which is deprecated (and really doesn't work at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like on your view controller should work:

```
public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(this);
}
```

Comment: This would remove it even when I add a new screen to the stack. So if go from this view to a new screen, and the event is fired, the view doesn't get the notification.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this is the common way of doing it. Then, on theviewwillappear, you register the notification again, and refresh the data on the view. This avoids having the view doing extra work while it's hidden, which saves battery and CPU time.

Comment: That's the thing, I do need be able to do a bit of work while it is hidden.  The notification isn't sent often enough for it to use much CPU time, but when it is sent, the screen may be further down in the view stack and the notification still needs to be handled.